# How can I format text horizontally to only begin after the bullet point?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting

Currently I have the following latex markup

```
\vspace{2.5px}

{\small $\bullet$} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam \vspace*{0.05cm} \\
{\small $\bullet$} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam \vspace*{0.05cm} \\
{\small $\bullet$} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam \vspace*{0.05cm} \\

\vspace{2.5px}
```

This results in the following generated output

[image]

Does anyone here know of an easy way to make sure the second line "ut labore..." is left aligned with the first line above it "Lorem ipsum"? In other words, make sure all the text begins after the bullet point?

Comment: Avoid manual formatting. Use standard LaTeX environments.

Comment: If you must, you can "outdent" the bullet... `\makebox[0pt][r]{\small \textbullet}~`

Answer (score 12):

Use an `itemize` environment. You can easily customize the look of the list with the package [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{
    label={\small\textbullet},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No need for `enumitem`

Comment: @lhf Indeed there is no need for it, but it's certainly easier to modify the list (for example, to change the labels or the spacing) with `enumitem`.

Comment: The reason I don't use `\begin{itemize}` is because I feel like it takes away my control over subtle horizontal and vertical margin settings. Is there really no other way to do this with the current markdown?

Comment: @AlanSTACK Well, you certainly could do it without `itemize`, as you could code your own version of it. But why not using `enumitem` to control the spacing?

Comment: What subtle horizontal and vertical margin settings are you wanting?

Comment: @AlanSTACK  it really goes against the entire latex design to use explicit spacing here. If you use latex at all you should use itemize for this.